# Shall I use 1 table with lot of NULL columns or more tables with no NULLs?

Tags: mysql, indexing, null, innodb

if it's worth to have 1 table with perhaps a lot of NULL columns or if it's better to have more tables with no NULLs? (in MYSQL DB with INNODB engine )

for eg: I have a header table which will store all the common things of a classified ad. like title, description etc...

Now if it is a vehicle ad you have to include special attributes such as fuel type, transmission type etc..

If it is a job ad you have to include attributes like job type, salary etc..

So now shall I use one header table with another two tables to store job attributes and vehicle attributes or Shall Include all of them in header table. So if it is a Job ad vehicle columns will held NULL values.

Please note that these Null able columns will use in some queries. SO I need to index them too.

Comment: This is a strange question. Let's say you have addresses to store, so you may want an address table. But parts of the address may be unknown or not they don't apply, say an optional company name, an optional postbox number. Are you really asking now whether you should make this an address_without_company_and_postbox table, plus a company_name_for_address table plus a postbox_for_address table, because these fields can be NULL? This doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: This question would probably get a better answer if you described some of the data that is likely to go into the table(s) and why it would have lots of `NULL` columns.

Comment: See the EAV tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the more of the attributes of your entities which overlap the more likely you are to want to put all of them into the same table.

If a job ad only shares 50% of its attributes with a vehicle ad then that might be good to put them in different tables.

Also depends on how the data is queried, if the query wants to get the next advertisement, and doesn't care whether the next one is for a job or an automobile then maybe they should be in the same table.